# Calculate probability of event

Tags: probability

Could you please help me with one task, please. I understand Probability theory more or less but cannot solve that one:

Given one deck of 52 playing cards, you draw two random cards. (The cards are drawn at the same time, so the selection is considered without replacement) Assuming a fair deck, what is P({both cards are aces})?

Comment: There are 4 aces in one deck. So the probability of pulling one ace is 4/52 = 1/13. Now the probability that we pull the second ace is 3/52. Using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)) we calculate probability of both events happening as 1/13 * 3/51 = 3/663.

Comment: @nikoliazekter it is only one deck so when you pull the first ace, the probability for the second one is 3/51 not 1/13 like Zdravko Danev mentionned

Comment: no, the probability for the second card is 3/51, not 3/52

Comment: Ooh, I suck at trying to solve easy problems too fast...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong group but...

P(first card is ace) = 4/52

P(second card is ace, when first one was ace) = 3/51

P(two aces) = P(first card is ace) * P(second card is ace, when first one was ace)